# How can I prove this integration result?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

The question is: how can I prove that:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^n\theta\ d\theta = \frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2}\big) \Gamma\big(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}n\big)}{\Gamma\big(1 + \frac{1}{2}n\big)}$$

Comment: Use the functional equation of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). It is almost the [Wallis integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: It's actually 2 Wallis integrals if you want to solve it this way.

Comment: oh thank you so much!! @YourAdHere

Answer (score 2):

The simple way, IMHO, is to check that identity holds for $n=0,1$ and both the LHS and the RHS satisfy the same recurrence relation; the LHS in virtue of integration by parts, the RHS in virtue of $\Gamma(z+1)=z\cdot\Gamma(z)$.